# .NET Compatibility Testing using Coded UI

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, .net-framework-version, distributed-testing

I have a test scenario where i want to validate the 4.5.2 version .net framework is being installed on a fresh windows environment (Win7, 8.1 and 10 - both 32 and 64 bit) along with the .exe which is being installed (Installation being one of the critical test scenario). I did the scripting in MS CodedUI Test. I want this script to be distributed on different machines. For this, I am using Test Controller and Agent setup. I am using VS2015 and TestAgent 2015. As Test Agent 2015 comes with .NET 4.6, my script is getting failed. Can i use any older versions of test agent to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Surely, the installer should fail if 4.5.2 is not available on the target?  Then there is no need to use CodedUI to validate it.